# How to run a test file (.go) from ethereum source?

Tags: go-ethereum, testing, unittesting

I have download the ethereum source from github and store the source in directory "~/EthereumSource/go-ethereum".

I have install all required software to build the source and successfully build the source from terminal using "make geth". I can run a private node using this geth.

Now I want to run the individual test files from source but failed.

**Command:**
"~/EthereumSource/go-ethereum/p2p/testing$ go test protocoltester.go"

**Error:**
protocoltester.go:35:2: cannot find package "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/log" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/log (from $GOROOT)

I have solved the problem using the following command (adding  build/env.sh)

**Command**
~/EthereumSource/go-ethereum$ build/env.sh go test ./p2p/testing/protocoltester.go

but now i have this **error** 
"p2p/testing/protocoltester.go:48:2: undefined: ProtocolSession"

I have also tried to run a different file server_test.go but failed

**Command :** ~/EthereumSource/go-ethereum$ build/env.sh go test ./p2p/server_test.go

Can anyone help me to show the proper steps to build those two files?

Thanks